# What are "_vti_cnf", "_vti_pvt", "_vti_script" and "_vti_txt" folders?

Tags: asp.net, frontpage

These folders appear in my .NET Web project. Why do they appear? Are they useful?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

They are used as part of the FrontPage server side extensions which do

- change tracking (mostly the `_vti_cnf`)
- code/script used by FrontPage specific controls (mostly the `_vti_script`)
- general settings

The old FrontPage program and Dreamweaver both used it.

The VTI part is actually because FrontPage was originally created by [Vermeer Technologies Incorporated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vermeer_Technologies_Incorporated) (note the acronym) and then bought by Microsoft and it just stuck.

Comment: Is it ok to just delete them then?

Comment: If you do not use Frontpage server side extensions then yes - note that SharePoint has similar folders _vti_bin that shouldn't be touched.

Answer (score 10):

They're part of the legacy [FrontPage server extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FrontPage_Server_Extensions). The `_vti_` prefix refers to Vermeer Technologies Inc., the original developer of FrontPage which was subsequently bought by Microsoft. They would appear if you installed these IIS extensions - they're not needed unless you have a legacy client which requires FrontPage extensions to be there.

Answer (score 7):

Expression web also uses them. In particularly the “`_vti_cnf`”, “`_vti_pvt`”. Do not delete them. The “`_vti_cnf`” holds your meta data. If you delete it, you can rebuild it by Recalculating Hyperlinks. You will find one in every folder.

Delete the “`_vti_pvt`” will cause you problems, in recognizing the local website. You should only see this in the main folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you have problems with updating the web server (EW or FP incorrectly uploads files that have already been updated), do not delete the contents of the _vti_cnf folder.  Usually, just recalculate the hyperlinks via EW or FP and that will take care of things.